# Dock "Find in files" in Visual Studio Community for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

Does anybody know how you can dock the "Search" -> "Find in files..." window in the sidebar so that it's always available in Visual Studio Community for Mac?
[image: Dock find in files to have it always available]

Can't find anywhere how to do this. On the Windows version of Visual Studio this is very easy and self explanatory.

I am using version 7.5 (build 1254).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not currently supported. The Find in Files is a dialog and it cannot be docked. Can you use the global search instead? This is the search text box at the top right of the IDE.

Comment: @MattWard: This seems to work indeed, but if you have the application in "full screen" mode, then the results are not displayed at all. So I thought that functionality was not working at all...

Comment: Seems OK for me in full screen mode. The window appears as you type in the top right hand text box. Then you can select something like Search in solution and then the search results will appear by default near the bottom of the IDE in a window that can be docked.

Comment: @MattWard: Could it be because I have attached a second screen to my Macbook Pro? If I run VS for Mac on one screen in full-screen mode and I run a search, then on the other (slave) screen I see the yellow popup message appear, but none of the results. If I am not running VS in full-screen, it's working just fine.

Comment: Possibly it could be due to having a second screen connected. There was a bug in an early Visual Studio for Mac 7.0 release but I do not believe that was related to a second screen - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/61479/search-does-not-show-suggestions-in-fullscreen-mod.html?childToView=248344

Comment: @Guppie70 there is an open Visual Studio 2017 for Mac issue for search results not being shown in full screen with a second monitor attached https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/183046/search-results-are-not-shown.html